# chrome devools console not sending any commands

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, qtwebkit

I am trying to debug an application that runs on qt-webkit. If I run the application with `--remote-debugging-port=<port>` command line argument I can access development tools in my chrome browser but I can't use the console at all.

I can't send commands in the console at all. I've tried with other application build on top of that and the problem is there too. One of the apps is `facebookeMessengerForDesktop` app.

Does anyone knows how to fix this or can you propose a way to send commands from the application without the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I could not find why this is not working but I found a workaround. 
You can define a new function that is used as the console. The function code is:

```
function v(command) {
    WebInspector.ConsoleView.prototype._appendCommand.call({_prompt: {text: ""}}, command, true);
}
```

You can use it in your browser console. When it is called it prints the command output in the context of the debugged application (the native one).